# Reduce and Sum Array positions

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have this array:

```
var likes = [4,7,3,11,3,73,78,34,7,13];
```

However, I'm only capable of use the length of 5 due to some restrictions. So I want to "convert" it to an array lenght of 5, and sum the other positions, by distribute them equally.

Does anybody have a clue how can I do this?

Comment: What does "by distributing them equally mean"? Can you provide an example of how your array should like after the conversion?

Comment: @Sankalp Mishra This is just an example, because the array is bigger than that one :P
I've tried to use a for cycle, and then use the method push to try join the positions, and sum them!

Comment: I agree, an explanation of "distributing them equally" would be quite helpful

Comment: @MCL For instance I want the array to became something like this:
new_array = [11,14,76,112,20]
In this case it was easy, because i just sum the 1st position with the 2nd, and so on. But when using non intenger numbers i've to do something more...

Comment: @zppinto There would be any logic of summing ??

Comment: In essence, you summed up every adjacent pair of numbers.

Comment: Just have a look at this link please: http://videofeedback.zurb.com/pullvotes/1/100.json?callback=
If you change the number "100" the array will have a new lenght and combine the positions by summing them! I want to do something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will solve your problem:

```
var likes = [4,7,3,11,3,73,78,34,7,13],
    result_array = [ ];

for(var i = 0; i < likes.length; i++)
{
   if(i % 2)
   {
       var new_val = likes[i - 1] + likes[i];
       result_array.push(new_val);
   }
}
```

See a working [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qrVeW/2/).

This will cause the new array to contain `[ 11, 14, 76, 112, 20 ]`, and will similarly increase in length when new values are added to the initial array.

Comment: It's something like that, but i can't use that way, because the sum it's not distributed equally! I want to have something like this  [11,14,76,112,20]. Because this way the likes are correctly disposed according to their real position.

Comment: OK, now I understand. Please see the updated jsFiddle and code.

Comment: Yeah, but now your output array length is bigger than the requested 5.

Comment: Yes. Read the comments. " If you change the number "100" the array will have a new lenght and combine the positions by summing them! "

Comment: @BenM MCL is right, it only works for a fixed array of 10. But i can work with that too. There is no problem.
Abou the link i posted here, is just an example...
Thank you.

Comment: What if the array does not contain an even number of values?

Comment: @zppinto If you want a fixed array size of 5, have a look at my answer

Comment: @BenM That's the problem now! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not very clear what you want exactly, I'll post an answer, too. This code will maintain a fixed length of 5 in your output array, no matter how large your input is.

```
var input = [4,7,3,11,3,73,78,34,25,7,13,19,2],
    max = 5,
    out = [];

var adjacentItems = Math.ceil(input.length / max);
for(var i=0; i<input.length; i += adjacentItems) {
    var aSum = 0;
    for(var j=i; j<Math.min(i+adjacentItems, input.length); j++) {
        aSum += input[j];
    }
    out.push(aSum);
}
```

[Check out the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rpdm/)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I'm looking to accomplish :)

Comment: Using `ceil()` isn't distributing them evenly, though?

Comment: @BenM To use the mathematical term "even distribution" for what was requested isn't very adequate anyway. What do you mean by it exactly?

Comment: @MCL Something went wrong in your code... When i change the max value, to 10, for example, the output will not be 10, but 7... It only works for 5 :(

Comment: @zppinto Did you try to fix it?

Comment: The problem is the "Math.ceil". Because it rounds the number upwards ... I've already tried "floor" and "round", but it's the same thing!

Comment: Yeah Ben! Now i see... :/ Any ideas?

Comment: @zppinto My algorithm expects an input array of at least twice the size of the `max` value. It was not meant to cater to every exception you could discover in the process and should merely show you a basic logic on how to tackle such a problem. If you have a concrete question regarding JavaScript syntax, someone around here will most likely be able to help you. If you generally have trouble developing algorithms for simple problems like this one, I suggest you start from scratch by learning how to solve arithmetical problems programmatically.

Comment: @MCL Thank you for your help... I just don't agree with you on this "for simple problems like this one" But ok! I will try to figure this out... or not! :(

Comment: @zppinto There is nothing to agree on. The mathematical complexity of your problem is, if anything, miniscule. Of course, no one is born a master. But if you try and improve, there should be no problem solving this. And frankly, I haven't seen you trying very hard. You didn't even provide any your own code.

Comment: @MCL my code evolves likes and times, and it's a bit confused to understand, and that's why I didn't provide it. I just posted here what I want to do in a simple way... However if you want to see a part of it, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/f5gtr/

Comment: @zppinto Providing code only makes sense, if you explain what it does or should do and what specifically doesn't work as expected. Posting a fiddle that doesn't run per se is escpecially useless. I suggest, you debug your program, locate the specific points in your code where stuff goes wrong and finally document all of it in your question above.

Comment: @MCL Yeah, i know! But i just post the code for you to see what I've been doing on my code. But, forget it. I will try to solve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i think i found the answer! :)
If you have any suggestion, please comment!

```
var likes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    result_array = [];
    result_array2 = [];    
    max = 8;

if (likes.length>max){
    result_array = likes;
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            var res = (likes.length - max) / max
            var new_val = (result_array[i] + (result_array[i+1] * res));
            result_array2.push(new_val);

    }

result_array = [];
result_array = result_array2;

}else{
result_array=likes
}

alert(result_array);
```

Please check the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qTpVz/1/)